# Should you say mashiv haruach if it's raining?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, weather, geshem-tal-ruach, summer

If it is currently raining in your location and it is not the proper time to say *mashiv haruach*, should you say it anyways?

*Mashiv haruach*, unlike *v'ten tal umatar*, is a recognition of God's power to make rain. It therefore seems appropriate to say it at the very moment that it is raining.

Comment: but isn't part of our prayers on behalf of Eretz Yisrael? Aren't we praising the one who RETURNS the rain when it is needed there, not just one who happens to make it rain here (I'm in Chu"l)?

Comment: @Danno I'm in Israel. I asked this question because it was raining this morning. It's also pretty close to the proper time. That might factor in.

Comment: @Scimonster Rain today in Israel is not a good thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rabbeinu Yona in Berachos writes that rain is in the blessing of גבורות because it brings life to the world, like the other things mentioned in the blessing (healing, etc.).  However, rain in the wrong time is a curse and causes rotting.  Thus it was used as a punishment in Sefer Shmuel for asking for a King.

So rain in the wrong time would not be relevant to the praise that is being given by its mention.

Comment: I bet the benefits of extra potable water outweigh any agricultural concerns nowadays.

Comment: @DoubleAA a) probably depends where b) I don't think it is a cost-benefit analysis, but a statement about the nature of the rain, i.e. the rain is not by definition nurturing, but rather doing the opposite.  Side benefits are side benefits.